# Rails EC2 Deployment - no such file to load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working against a variety of constraints that are troubling an EC2 Rails deployment. I'm not allowed to use Capistrano because I cannot save this application to any public git repository (like GitHub) and I also need to retain complete control over which instance on EC2 the Rails application is installed to and be able to modify this easily (adding load balancers, auto-scalers, etc.) on the fly from the AWS Console, so I also cannot use Rubber.

I finally resorted to simply ssh'ing my Rails application directory over to the EC2 instance, but am running into a 'no such file to load' error when running bundle install, *specifically* the **Time** gem. Because this is an 'integrated' gem, I think I might just be overlooking something simple. Here are the things that I've tried:

- I've used RVM to manage my versions of ruby, rails, rubygems, etc.
- Deleting my Gemfile.lock file and re-running bundle-install
- Including 'Time' in my GemFile and re-running bundle-install

This application runs without issue on my local development environment, so what am I overlooking?

Note: I am REQUIRED to host on a single EC2 instance. Otherwise, I'd simply deploy to EBS, Heroku, etc.

Comment: Could you put the exact error message - which `no such file to load`?

Comment: It was a dumb mistake. I had written require 'Time' instead of require 'time'. This worked fine on my local instance, but got gummed up on the EC2 ubuntu instance for whatever reason.

Comment: Can you post a full answer ?

Comment: On it, Rico - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a stupid mistake, also detailed in this question: [heroku - cant run rake db:migrate - no such file --Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19044755/heroku-cant-run-rake-dbmigrate-no-such-file-time)

I incorrectly had a require statement in a controller for 'Time', instead of 'time'. This was allowed locally, but my ubuntu server ruby environment was not as forgiving. Changing the 'T' to a 't' in my controller and running 'bundle install' resolved this issue completely.